# Laravel Nova - Let user chose which fields/columns are displayed on index

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel 9 and Nova 4 to create an admin panel and recently got the request you can see in the title.

Is there any way to let the user dynamically select which fields of the resource are shown on the index instead of hard-coding the visibility?

I want to show/hide full columns of the resource via the click of a button.

Maybe i searched for the wrong stuff I haven't found any information on this. Neither here on StackOverflow nor anywhere else.